# How to convert values inside nested lists into sets?

Tags: python, set, nested-lists

I was wondering if anyone has any ideas of how to convert the values contained in nested lists, so you end up with a list of a list of sets? 
e.g I have:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8], [1, 4, 5, ...], ...]
```

I am trying to convert this so the `0` is `{0}`, `1` is `{1}`. i.e.:

```
[[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {0}, {6}, {7}, {8}], [{1}, {4}, {5}, ...], ...]
```

I currently have:

```
def ToSets(list):
    for i in range(0,9): #row
        for j in list[i]:
            list[i][j] = set(list[i][j])
   print(list)
```

I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: What sense does it make to convert each element into a singleton set?

Comment: You can achieve it by: `[[{y} for y in x] for x in my_list]`. But why do you want that?

Comment: Your question title is misleading. You are not converting the nested lists. You are replacing the *values* in the nested list with single-value sets.

Comment: Question: you currently attempt to update the lists *in place*, so other references to the list will see the changes. How important is this? Is it okay to create a *new* list of lists of sets instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set()` takes the values from *an iterable* and adds each value separately. You passed in an `int`, which is not iterable at all.

You would have to wrap your individual values in an iterable, like a list:

```
list[i][j] = set([list[i][j]])
```

A much easier option would be to use the `{...}` set literal notation:

```
list[i][j] = {list[i][j]}
```

If the list doesn't need updating *in place*, you can also use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions) to create a new list-of-lists-of-sets structure:

```
def to_sets(l):
    return [[{i} for i in row] for row in l]
```

If you must update in place, at least just iterate over the outer rows, and use `enumerate()` to generate the indices for the inner columns:

```
def to_sets_inplace(l):
    for row in l:
        for i, value in enumerate(row):
            row[i] = {value}
```

If you have other references to the original list of lists, stick with with setting the values directly, otherwise use the list comprehensions. Both work:

```
>>> def to_sets(l):
...     return [[{i} for i in row] for row in l]
...
>>> demo = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8], [1, 4, 5]]
>>> def to_sets_inplace(l):
...     for row in l:
...         for i, value in enumerate(row):
...             row[i] = {value}
...
>>> to_sets(demo)
[[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {0}, {6}, {7}, {8}], [{1}, {4}, {5}]]
>>> to_sets_inplace(demo)
>>> demo
[[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {0}, {6}, {7}, {8}], [{1}, {4}, {5}]]
```

Comment: I would like to use this method, but when I try your suggestion (list[i][j] = {list[i][j]}) I'm getting a "unhasable type: set" error.

Comment: @user9080591 probably some of your elements are already updated to set value with the execution of your previous code. Please create a new list and pass to the function, it should work

Comment: @user9080591: that means your *real* data already has some sets, you can't put a `set()` object inside another set.

Comment: @user9080591: check your data. You have three options: 1. try again with a clean dataset that has no sets in them. 2. skip the set objects (you could use a `try...except` or use `isinstance()` to test for the object type) and 3. convert sets to `frozenset()` objects before wrapping them in a set.

Comment: I just have a list of lists - no sets in them at all. Moinuddin, your first way works fine, but I want to do it using two 'for' statements so I can change the set 0 to another set. I can't see if there is a way for doing this using your simpler method?

Comment: @user9080591: there is very little difference between the two methods. I've added an improved version that alters the values in-place, and added a demo for both approaches.

Comment: I've added what I got to work in my original post. Thanks for your help. I had a look at your edited post and am confused by this line: for i, value in enumerate(row). Would you be able to explain what this is doing please?

Comment: @user9080591: Ah, you have an *additional requirement* you didn't mention before. That really should be a separate question. But you can use a *conditional expression* to insert `'p'` instead of a set if the value is 0: `return [[{i} if i else 'p' for i in row] for row in l]`

Comment: @user9080591: the `{i} if i else 'p'` expression replaced the `{i}` version in the answers here; if `i` is a true value (so not `0` or an empty string, etc.) then a set with the value is created, otherwise the string `'p'` is used. For every value in the inner lists.

Comment: That is a beautiful solution. Much cleaner than what I was doing. Thanks. Finally, I still don't understand your "in_place" solution. What on earth is going on here:     "for i, value in enumerate(row):" :)

Comment: @user9080591: See [What does enumerate mean?](//stackoverflow.com/a/22171593) `i` is the index that `enumerate()` adds. So you have both the value and the index in the inner list, letting you assign the result of putting the value in a set back into the original `row` list at the same index.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass each element in `{}` to create a set, otherwise you have to pass `set()` an iterable sequence, which a single integer is not.

```
>>> data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
>>> [[{j} for j in i] for i in data]
[[{1}, {2}, {3}], [{4}, {5}, {6}]]
```

Comment: Note that the OP updates the list **in place**, while you produce a new list. This is a crucial differences that you need to make explicit.